# What does disableOriginalConstructor do?

Tags: php, phpunit

In phpunit documentations is example:

```
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder($originalClassName)
                     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                     ->disableOriginalClone()
                     ->disableArgumentCloning()
                     ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
                     ->getMock();
```

What does `disableOriginalConstructor()` and `disableOriginalClone()` do, since the constructor and clone in mocks are disabled by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do exactly what they say. Look again at the example you gave.
You first create a mock builder and then customize it to generate what you want. If you would have just called `$this->getMockBuilder()->getMock();` you would have received a different test double.
You would have received a double that would call the original constructor so you would also have to provide the constructor's arguments like this:

```
$this->getMockBuilder()
    ->setConstructorArgs()
    ->getMock();
```

Now take a look at the `createMock()` method in `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. This method explicitly provides some of the defaults you were mentioning. This is why the `createMock()` works the way it works.

To sum it up: `$this->createMock()` and `$this->getMockBuilder()->getMock()` do not do the same thing. They differ in that `createMock()` generates the test double with some defaults and the the builder is not doing it.